# Переместить папку с файлами в другую папку. Как лучше?

Tags: python, pathlib

Есть такая структура директорий:

```
   test_0    
    |-----level_1
    |-----level_1_a
    |-----level_1_b
    | ... (и т.д.)  ....      
    |-----task     
           |----file.csv   
           |----rest.py     
            ... (и т.д.)  ....
```

Нужно перенести папку с файлами в заданную папку.   То есть, например, в level_1:

```
   test_0    
    |-----level_1
        |-----task     
               |----file.csv   
               |----rest.py     
               ... (и т.д.)  ....
    |-----level_1_a
    |-----level_1_b
    | ... (и т.д.)  ....
```

Ну и вот код,

```
from pathlib import Path

work_dir = Path() / "test_0"
task_dir = work_dir / "task"

folder_move_to = work_dir / "level_1" / "task"
folder_move_to.mkdir()

for file in task_dir.iterdir():
    file.rename(work_dir / "level_1" / "task" / file.name)

task_dir.rmdir()
```

Похожие варианты которого приведены, например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file).
Все почти хорошо. Но остается ощущение что как-то это "тяжеловато". Должно быть лучше))

Вопрос: Какой способ перемещения папки в данном случае лучше,
безопаснее, короче ...

Comment: Если всё это в пределах одного диска, то не нужно переносить каждый файл по отельности, достаточно сделать один rename на всю папку и всё

Comment: @andreymal  добавьте ответ,  я удалю "свой" )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, в моей ситуации, когда все на одном диске, можно просто переименовать папку, содержащую диски. Тогда она переедет куда надо вместе с файлами.

то есть вместо

```
for file in task_dir.iterdir():
    file.rename(work_dir / "level_1" / "task" / file.name)
```

достаточно ОДНОГО ПЕРЕИМЕНОВАНИЯ.

```
 task_dir.rename(work_dir / "level_1" / "task")
```

Бинго!
Спасибо @andreymal